# How to make routable OSM map

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I have some routable data for testing my pgRouting functions, and everything is fine. Now I have to download some more countries from OSM. I downloaded Germany shape files, but OSM maps are not routable. OK, next step, I found osm2pgrouting Import Tool but it works only on Linux, I need Windows version.
Is there any possibility to make OSM map routable on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the OSM chapter of the pgRouting workshop: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html
To import your data on Windows you could try osm2po (http://osm2po.de). It's written in Java, so it may work.

Comment: I did it with osm2po! It was not so easy, I had some errors, etc … but I did it. Thank you Daniel!

Comment: I did it with Greece, but for Germany I got Out of memory error.

Answer (score 4):

I have used OSM2PostGIS for Windows without issue

*"OSM2PostGIS is a new tool for importing data from the OpenStreetMap XML (.osm) files to a PostgreSQL database with the correct geometry projection, spatial reference (PostGIS), and directed topology for routing (pgRouting). Routing cost calculation is aware of one-way roads, speed limits, etc."*

http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2PostGIS.html

Underdark has made a very good beginners guide.

http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

Comment: Do you know how active osm2PostGIS community is? Their Sourceforge page looks deserted.

Comment: I have OSM2PostGIS, but I thought it is for Linux. I don’t know how to use it on Windows.

Comment: Yes, Underdark has very useful posts.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use our OSM converter. It turns the OSM files into SHP, which you can then import into PostGIS (or even better use it with our routing products). In any case the converter is aimed at making OSM routable and highlight errors in the data.

Find it at http://www.routeware.dk

Comment: I tried it, it looks nice but I get the error “Out of memory”. I have 4 GB RAM.

Comment: What should I do to resolve this? I like this converter but for now it is not useful for me :(

Comment: Is it Germany you have tested with?

Comment: I tested with Greece because it is smaller...

Comment: Right now I tried osm2po with Germany and I got Out of memory error.

Comment: I have tested Greece too. Greece.osm is a 1 GB file and it requires 840 MB while converterting. Takes 2-3 minutes. Shouldn't be a problem with 4 GB RAM.

Comment: I don't know. I check SHP and Memory option. I tried with Database and Direct file option and I have the same error. Could you send me somehow print screen picture to see your options. I have windows XP.

Comment: contact me through the e-mail you can see on my website.