# How to get started with pgRouting and OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I have followed these instructions to install PostgreSQL and pgRouting on our Ubuntu server:

http://obsessivecoder.com/2010/02/01/installing-postgresql-8-4-postgis-1-4-1-and-pgrouting-1-0-3-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/

I am working with united_kingdom.highway.osm, It all seemed to go ok.

I have pgAdminIII on my Windows machine, and can connect to my PostgreSQL db and I see the tables: `geometry_columns, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_nodes, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_rels, planet_osm_roads, planet_osm_ways, spatial_ref_sys`.

Now, I have not done anything with PostgreSQL before, and I am looking for the simplest possible way of getting something out to show it is working, like finding the distance between two UK points.

Answer (score 6):

OpenStreetMap road data is NOT routable by default. You'll have to use a tool that creates a routable network from the data. There are many around and since you work on Ubuntu, most of them should work for your. 
Also see the answers to this question [How to make routable OSM map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20968/how-to-make-routable-osm-map)

Note that "The current version of osm2pgrouting needs to load all data into memory, which makes it fast but also requires a lot or memory for large datasets.".

I had more luck with osm2po which doesn't seem to have these memory restrictions. For a full tutorial go to http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/pgrouting/

Comment: I have run osm2pgrouting, but am not sure if it worked, how can I check? From the output it does not give me any indication of wheather or not it succeeded. I mostly see "Trying to load data" and "Trying to parse data".

Comment: I imagine the whole UK dataset is rather huge. It might well exceed the capabilities of osm2pgrouting

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! So you recommend using osm2po? Are there any tutorials on using osm2po on ubuntu?

Comment: You just need to download and extract the java .jar file. It makes no difference which OS you use (as long as java is installed).

Comment: I am trying to use osm2po, and it runs, and then waits for requests on http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService. Are there any instructions on configuring apache for this? If I configure apache to listen on port 8888, and rerun osm2po, then osm2po crashes. Any assistance would we appriciated! many thanks mark

Comment: Maybe @Carsten can help.

Comment: FATAL  Exception at Mon Aug 06 14:58:09 BST 2012
       Message: Address already in use
       Class: java.net.BindException
       Stacktrace: <-- I get this message if apache2/ports.conf is configured to listen on port 8888.

Comment: sounds like Apache blocks the port and osm2pg routing therefore cannot bind to it. Apache is in the way.

Comment: INFO   135,770,459 Bytes cached
INFO   Graph is in memory - 229,354k free
INFO   Services started. Waiting for requests at
       http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService
now in the browser I enter http://192.168.7.66:8888/Osm2poService since I am running Osm2poService on a Ubuntu Server. I have opened port 8888, but I see nothing in the browser. Any ideas? Thanks mark :)

Comment: ok, easy answer, just replace localhost with the ip address in the config file!

Answer (score 1):

This question got referenced from [another one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86908/prepare-osm-file-for-pgrouting-use), but this question (including answers) is quite old and outdated in the meanwhile.

To get started with pgRouting and OSM, you best start with the [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/)