# How to extract all Way elements tagged as highways from OSM data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, road

I want to extract/filter in all Way elements within a specific region tagged as 'highway' from an OSM file. I am currently thinking of using a Python library called osmread (by A Dezhin) that I stumbled upon online. It's pretty straightforward. Here's an example usage that I got from his [repository](https://github.com/dezhin/osmread).

```
from osmread import parse_file, Way

highway_count = 0
for entity in parse_file('foo.osm.bz2'):
if isinstance(entity, Way) and 'highway' in entity.tags:
    highway_count += 1

print "%d highways found" % highway_count
```

This is good enough, but I was wondering if qGIS also has a similar function that allows users to filter elements (Node, Way, Relation) given a specific set of criteria. I would prefer to use qGIS for the 'instant' visualization.

In the end, I hope to build a road network and conduct some analysis.

Thanks, all, in advance.

Comment: How did this project turn out?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS comes with an OSM plugin which can open .osm files or download smaller regions directly from the web. The result is immediately visualized. Large .osm files will take long to parse. Tags will be written to the attribute table where you can use the usual QGIS query building tools to filter features.

Note that the OSM plugin in QGIS 1.8 is far from perfect and will be replaced by a new version in 2.0 - but it should do the trick.

Another thing worth noting is that the OSM street network is *not routable by default* since street network edges are not necessarily split at each street intersection. Some serious preprocessing is needed before standard routing algorithms can be applied. See [How to make routable OSM map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20968/how-to-make-routable-osm-map) for pointers.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, I have already installed the OSM plugin. I just noticed though that the attribute table has very limited columns for tags. Is this correct? For example, lat and lon information are not there. 

Anyway, I think I have found the information that I have been wanting to extract under Vector > Analysis Tools > Line intersections. Unfortunately, I do not know how I can filter the intersections in terms of Highway classifications (e.g. I want to exclude 'residential' highways). Is this even possible to do with the current version of the OSM plugin+QGIS?

Comment: If you have a follow-up question about filtering intersections, please open a new thread. Try to be as specific as possible about which criteria should be used to select an intersection.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Since I am new to qGIS, I just found out that there's a Query Builder. This is what I was looking for.